# Positioning of fielders in cricket

Tags: rules, cricket

In a test match is there any rule that minimum number of fielders should be present on the off side or the leg side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, In all forms of cricket, only two fielders are allowed in the quadrant between the fielding positions of square leg and long stop.

This is to prevent the outlawed and controversial bodyline tactics from being used.

courtesy [bodyline tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodyline)

Comment: what is long stop?

Comment: A fielder in the fine leg region. It basically implies behind square

Answer (score 4):

There is a maximum of 6 fielders on either side of the wicket for one day cricket, but no restrictions (other than no more than 2 behind square leg) in test cricket.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is nothing like that. All the fielders can stand anywhere except the keeper and bowler. There is no rule that says minimum or maximum on any side. England in particular tend to set the field on one side in earlier days.

Comment: A maximum of two are allowed behind square on leg. So there is a rule for maximum. :)